# Trying to grasp recursion functions

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, recursion

I am trying to grasp the concept of recursion and I just cannot make sense of it.
Can someone please explain to me why it works the way it does?

When I see this code, I expect the only thing to print is 1, as that is when it finally quits calling itself, and that is what it returns on the last call.

```
def Fib(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)


print Fib(10)
```

I also try doing this, and expect it to print 1, but only get None

```
def foo(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        foo(n-1)
print foo(10)
```

EDIT: I appreciate the help that has been provided. I still am just not seeing the connection that my brain needs for the AH-HA! This is more likely due to a limitation of my experience more so than the community's ability to explain my problem. Hopefully the information provided will be able to help me in the future when I come back to this, and others as well. Thank you! I would give up-votes, but do not have the required reputation to do so, sorry!

Comment: "trying to grasp recursion functions" - grasp them by the tail ;)

Comment: To understand recursion, you must understand recursion :P

Answer (score 1):

```
class noisyOne():
    def __init__(self, val=1):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        print("**Adding {0} with {1}**".format(self.val, other.val))
        return noisyOne(self.val + other.val)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)



def Fib(n, side):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        print ("return 1 : called from {0}".format(side))
        return noisyOne(1)
    print("return Fib({0}) + Fib({1}) : called from {2}".format(n-1, n-2, side))
    return Fib(n-1, 'Fib({0})'.format(n-1)) + Fib(n-2, 'Fib({0})'.format(n-2))


print (Fib(5, 'Fib(5)'))

# return Fib(4) + Fib(3) : called from Fib(5)   :                             Fib(5) = Fib(4) + Fib(3)
# return Fib(3) + Fib(2) : called from Fib(4)   : Fib(4) = Fib(3) + Fib(2) -> Fib(5) = Fib(3) + Fib(2) + Fib(3)
# return Fib(2) + Fib(1) : called from Fib(3)   : Fib(3) = Fib(2) + Fib(1) -> Fib(5) = Fib(2) + Fib(1) + Fib(2) + Fib(3)
# return 1 : called from Fib(2)                 : Fib(2) = 1               -> Fib(5) = 1      + Fib(1) + Fib(2) + Fib(3)
# return 1 : called from Fib(1)                 : Fib(1) = 1               -> Fib(5) = 1      + 1      + Fib(2) + Fib(3)
# **Adding 1 with 1**                           : 1 + 1  = 2               -> Fib(5) = 2               + Fib(2) + Fib(3)
# return 1 : called from Fib(2)                 : Fib(2) = 1               -> Fib(5) = 2               + 1      + Fib(3)
# **Adding 2 with 1**                           : 2 + 1  = 3               -> Fib(5) = 3                        + Fib(3)
# return Fib(2) + Fib(1) : called from Fib(3)   : Fib(3) = Fib(2) + Fib(1) -> Fib(5) = 3                        + Fib(2) + Fib(1)
# return 1 : called from Fib(2)                 : Fib(2) = 1               -> Fib(5) = 3                        + 1 + Fib(1)
# return 1 : called from Fib(1)                 : Fib(1) = 1               -> Fib(5) = 3                        + 1 + 1
# **Adding 1 with 1**                           : 1 + 1  = 2               -> Fib(5) = 3                        + 2
# **Adding 3 with 2**                           : 3 + 2  = 5               -> Fib(5) = 5
# 5
```

Comment: This is the part that I actually understand, I lose where it decides that it is going to return the last sequence out to the original print call in my script above. The recursion of the function makes sense, its the output of that recursion that I really don't understand. Maybe I just can't get past the concept that my brain wants to treat this as a loop and when it hits it's escape, it is supposed to do what the escape says. So when I see that it brings it all the way down to 1, and it returns the actual 1, I expect it to print that 1

Comment: Eventually all the recursion paths reach the `return 1`. And then it simply returns like a normal function

Comment: @user3724263 It doesn't return the 1 to the print function though. It returns the 1 to its caller, which is not the print function if `n>2`, but rather is another instance of the `Fib` function.

Comment: Yes they return to the caller, which in turn return to their caller and so on. until the original caller is reached and returned to the print function

Comment: @Hassan I edited my answer to show both the execution and how the return values propagate out to the original caller.

Answer (score 1):

The code won't print 1 because the only way for the function to return 1 is when the parameter `n` is either 1 or 2. So when you say `print Fib(10)`, the result will not be 1.

Instead, the control goes to the next line after the `if` statement (`return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)`), which calls `Fib` again, this time with 9 and 8. The result of these two function calls will be added together and returned.

So now `Fib` runs with the parameter `n` set to 9. Since 9 does not equal 1 or 2, again the last line of the `Fib` function will run, and `Fib` will be called again for the values 8 and 7.

This continues, until `Fib` is called with `n=1` or `n=2`, in which case `Fib` will return 1. It returns 1 to its caller, which was the instance of the `Fib` function when it was called with `n=3`. So here's what happens when you call `Fib` with `n=3`:

3 is not 1 or 2, so again, control goes to the last line of `Fib`, `return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)`. This time, this line calls `Fib` on `n-1`, which is 2, and `n-2`, which is 1. Both these function calls evaluate to 1, so the function here returns 1+1 to its caller.

Its caller then returns the value of the addition to its caller, which returns the value of its addition to its caller, until the caller is the `print` line, which just prints the result.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it breaks it all the way out, hits the escape, and then works its way back to the solution?

Comment: Kind of. Try being the Python interpreter yourself, and run `Fib(4)`. It may take a minute, but you'll see each and every step, and it may help you understand.

Comment: So why is it that when I do

    def foo(n):
        if n == 1:
            return 5
        else:
            return foo(n-1)
    print foo(100)

that will return 5, but the fib doesnt because it runs two functions in recursion?

Comment: @user3724263 That code recurses just like the original code, but when 5 is finally returned, the function that gets it doesn't do anything with it, like adding it to something else as in the original code. Instead, it just returns 5 to its caller, which returns 5 to its caller, and so on, until 5 is returned to the `print` function which just prints the 5.

Comment: @user3724263 Try that same code, but instead of `return foo(n-1)`, try `return foo(n-1) + 1`, and see what you get when calling `foo` with different values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key you're missing is that method calling creates a *stack*. So think about the sequence of calls.

The first call is with the argument `10`. So here's our call stack:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
```

where our current subroutine (method) is at the bottom.

Then `Fib(10)` calls the subroutine with the argument `9`, so our call stack looks like this:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
```

All the way down to `Fib(2)`:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
Fib(8)
Fib(7)
Fib(6)
Fib(5)
Fib(4)
Fib(3)
Fib(2)
```

At this point, `Fib(2)` goes into the `if` block, and we hit `return 1`. Now here's the key: `return` only **pops one element off the stack**. So when `Fib(2)` returns, we go back up to `Fib(3)`:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
Fib(8)
Fib(7)
Fib(6)
Fib(5)
Fib(4)
Fib(3)
```

Now that the first item in the sum is computed, `Fib(3)` can move onto the second item in the sum. This makes it call `Fib(1)`:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
Fib(8)
Fib(7)
Fib(6)
Fib(5)
Fib(4)
Fib(3)
Fib(1)
```

which also returns immediately:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
Fib(8)
Fib(7)
Fib(6)
Fib(5)
Fib(4)
Fib(3)
```

After `Fib(1)` returns, `Fib(3)` can finally return:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
Fib(8)
Fib(7)
Fib(6)
Fib(5)
Fib(4)
```

And then `Fib(4)` calls `Fib(2)`, much like `Fib(3)` called `Fib(1)` before:

```
__main__
Fib(10)
Fib(9)
Fib(8)
Fib(7)
Fib(6)
Fib(5)
Fib(4)
Fib(2)
```

and so on and so forth. If the final `return` is what's confusing you, keep in mind that `return` only ends the *current subroutine* and throws you back into the previous one.

On that second method you present, you're getting `None` because it should be `return foo(n-1)`, not just `foo(n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot return the value of foo(n-1) which will not be a recursion function, it will return None by default. Try this way:

```
def foo(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return foo(n-1)
print foo(10)
```

When you call the function, no matter which the number is, it will return 1 forever.

First, if n == 1 it return 1, else if n=5, it return foo(4), and foo(4) return foo(3), foo(3) return foo(2), foo(1) return 1. So if you print foo(100) or  foo(200) it will be 1 forever.

Remember that n must be a positive number or you will get this:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Just print out the process:

```
def Fib(n):
    print "Call number", n
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    print '\n now is', Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
    return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)

print Fib(10)
```

May help PO understand.

Comment: Yeah sorry, typo here, i have it that way in my script.

EDIT: NVM, just noticed what I must not have. so now I get 1, but how does the Fib one work exactly? I get why it was returning None now, because there was no return call in the else. DOH sorry, tired.

How is it that the Fib one doesn't just eventually return 1 since that is the escape?

Comment: It return 1, so what's your result?

Comment: I understand the foo one now, as i forgot the return, and it was returning nothing. But as for the Fib one, why does it return the last Fib sequence instead of 1 when it hits the escape?